# How do you declare a Func with an anonymous return type?

Tags: c#, anonymous-function, anonymous-types

I need to be able to do this:

```
var getHed = () => 
{
    // do stuff
    return new { Property1 = value, Property2 = value2, etc...};
};

var anonymousClass = getHed();
```

But I get an error which indicates I need to explicitly declare getHed.

How do I declare Func such that T is the anonymous type I am returning?

In case you are curious why I need to do this, it is because I am using 3rd party software that allows customization code, but only within a single method. This can become very difficult to manage. I had the idea that I could use anonymous methods to help keep the procedural code organized. In this case, for it to help, I need a new class, which I cannot define except anonymously.

Comment: you cant. two work arounds : 1-write a class , 2-use dynamic(which is slow)

Comment: @ChrisF You _can_ but the caller must use `dynamic` or reflection to do anything useful with it.

Comment: You don't. That's the whole point of anonymous types -- they're anonymous. You can't declare functions returning a particular anonymous type. You could return a `Tuple`, though accessing its members is not as convenient.

Comment: Tuple is getting a little convoluted. M.kazem's suggestion seems to be the best approach

Comment: You can declare methods returning a `T` and then coerce the compiler into working out the `T` for you which can then be an anonymous type, but not with an anonymous method, it requires a compiler trick like the answers here provide.

Comment: @ChrisF But he's *not* returning it back to the caller.  The anonymous type is being used entirely within the scope of a single method.

Comment: @JeroenMostert As mentioned in my previous comment, the anonymous type isn't being used outside the scope of the one method.

Comment: @Servy: yes, you are a clever cookie. As long as the code does allow that extra static function, you're golden.

Comment: The solution that ended up working is to declare getHed as Func<dynamic>. I believe my case is faithful to the intended use of the dynamic keyword, since I am trying to interact with anonymous data in a single method (see http://www.ducons.com/blog/new-features-in-c-4-0#Dynamic_types). Thank you @M.kazemAkhgary !

Answer (score 25):

As is basically always the case with anonymous types, the solution is to use a generic method, so that you can use method type inference:

```
public static Func<TResult> DefineFunc<TResult>(Func<TResult> func)
{
    return func;
}
```

You can now write:

```
var getHed = DefineFunc(() => 
{
    // do stuff
    return new { Property1 = value, Property2 = value2, etc...};
});
```

Comment: Best known as [`Linq.Func`](http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx/) helper method.

Comment: I love this solution. However, in my case, I do not have the freedom to write this static function. Is there such a method in the standard libraries? I only have access to the standard .NET libraries and whatever the 3rd party supplies. I do not have the option of asking them to provide something like this.

Comment: @PriceJones No, there is no.

Comment: It works with only TResult. Any generic TIn type breakes the interferation.

Comment: @SerG The question is asking about a situation involving a `Func<T>`, not constructing a delegate that has any inputs.  If you're in a different situation than what is being asked here, you should ask a new question.

Comment: I just added a note for those who faces the same in the future.

Comment: Actually, this solution can work with inputs too.  If you define public static Func<TIn, TResult> DefineFunc<TIn, TResult>(Func<TIn, TResult> func)
{
    return func;
}  You just need to specify the input types explicitly. This won't work: var f = DefineFunc(i => { new {A = 1}});, but this will: var f = DefineFunc((int i) => { new {A = 1}});.

Answer (score 9):

Use the following generic method to let the compiler infer the anonymous type for you:

```
public static Func<T> MakeFn<T>(Func<T> f)
{
    return f;
}
```

Usage:

```
var getHed = MakeFn(() => new { Property1 = ..., Property2 = ... });
var anonymousClass = getHed();

// you can now access Property1 and Property2
var test = anonymousClass.Property1;
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, it can't be done.

You need an additional, generic, method to trick the compiler into inferring the `T` for you to be the anonymous type, such as the other answers here provides.

However, since you've written that this is a special case where everything has to fit inside a single method, then no, it cannot be done.

The compiler does not allow this syntax:

```
var x = () => ...
```

It needs this:

```
DelegateType x = () => ...
```

As such, you need to trick the compiler into working out the right type for `DelegateType`, which likely is `Func<(anonymous type here)>`, and this can only be done through type inference.

However, type inference and generic parameters requires the method to be generic, and thus the need for the additional method that has to be a generic method to help the compiler do this type inference.

Since you need to stay inside one method...