# Why you cannot declare a field and property as having an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, anonymous-types, anonymous-class

I ran into a problem while doing my job, which is porting software from flash AS3 to .NET/Mono. In AS3 code base I can find many `Object` declarations that are initialized like this:

```
private const MAPPING:Object =
{
    ssdungf:'flydung',
    ssdungt:'flydung',
    superfutter:'superfeed'
}
```

The best option for me would be in C# using anonymous type like this:

```
var MAPPING = new
{
    ssdungf = "flydung",
    ssdungt = "flydung",
    superfutter = "superfeed"
};
```

The problem is... well let me quote MSDN ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)):

> You cannot declare a field, a property, an event, or the return type of a method as having an anonymous type

But they don't say why.

So the question remains: **why you cannot declare a field and property as having an anonymous type? Why .NET creators stripped it from that option?**

I am getting warning here from SO that my question appears subjective, but I think it is not at all - there need to be objective reason for that.

As for me, I don't see any obstacles for that but somehow it is not supported. As compiler can easily generate the type for field or property of class, in a same manner as it does for local variables.

The option for me was to use `dynamic` type but unfortunately Mono engine I am using is stripped from that.

Also the option for me is to use object type and using later reflection to find these fields:

```
 private static readonly object MAPPING = new
 {
     ssdungf = "flydung",
     ssdungt = "flydung",
     superfutter = "superfeed"
 };
```

But using reflection is this situation is dirty I would say.

I tried to find answer, but I really didn't find any. Here are some SO answers to similar questions, but they don't answer why:

[Can a class property/field be of anonymous type in C# 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982222/can-a-class-property-field-be-of-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp-4-0)

[Declaring a LIST variable of an anonymous type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997888/declaring-a-list-variable-of-an-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp)

[How do you declare a Func with an anonymous return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151747/how-do-you-declare-a-func-with-an-anonymous-return-type)

Comment: @HimBromBeere true, I didn't think about it, but still fields remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why you cannot declare a field and property as having an anonymous type?

Because C# is statically typed, so any memory location has to be given a type, and declaration does so. With locals we can infer from context if its initialised at the same time as declaration with `var` but that is a shorthand for a type that is usable even when the type hasn't got a name.

What would a field with an anonymous type, that is to say a statically-bound but indescribable type, mean?

`dynamic` would indeed be the closest analogy to the code you are porting, but since that isn't available to you, you might consider using an `IDictionary<string, object>` (which incidentally is how `ExpandoObject`, which is often used with `dynamic` to have objects that behave more like javascrpt objects, works behind the scenes). This would be slower and less type-safe than if you created a class for the object needed, but can work.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I find this one the most valuable. You write "Because C# is statically typed, so any memory location has to be given a type, and declaration does so", but compiler can do same trick creating hidden Type, and memory location will have a Type. Maybe I don't understand fully your answer.

Comment: But then what would that mean in code that uses it? "There's a thing you don't know how to use at `_someField`"? Okay, we could use `var` but it's still not very useful to the programmer to have `someValue` when they don't know what type it is except by looking at some (perhaps unavailable) source.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that we always care what type a field (or any other member) is. Anonymity (whether anonymous types, anonymous functions or whatever) makes our life easier by getting rid of details we don't care about, and as such is only useful when we really don't care.

Answer (score 0):

The problem on an anoynmous property is: how do you get/set it?

Suppose it would work:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyField = new { TheValue = "Hello World" };
}
```

Now in your consuming code you´d write code to read the code:

```
MyClass m = new MyClass();
m.MyField.TheValue = "newValue";
```

How was this different from having a type for `MyField`? All you´d get is that you can omit two or three lines of code whilst gaining nothing. But I think you might produce many problems as no-one knows what he can assign to/expect from that member.

Furthermore you can´t do much with an anonymous object, basically you can just set it and read it. There are no methods (except `Equals`and `GetHashCode` inherited from `object`) that you can call so the opportunities are quite low.

Last but not least an anonymous object is usually used as temporaryily, for example within a `Select`-statement. When you use it you say: this type is going to be used only within the current specific scope and can be ignored by the entire world as internal implementation-detail. Creating a property of an anonymous type will expose such a detail to the outside. Of course you could argue that the designers could at least allow them for `private` members, but I guess doing so would bypass the complete concept of accessability for nothing.

Comment: Thanks, your last point is good. But you think that is why .NET creators didn't let to do it?

Comment: @JerrySwitalski Only they will know.